# SQL How to update 'Deleted' row

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, triggers, delete-row

[image]

When UPDATE statement is entered a trigger is activated so that at the end the both the original and updated rows kept and can be displayed if the user wants to.

The orignal row's (Edited marked as Y) values are correct but the updated row (Edited marked as NULL) should have the `CreationDate` same as the orignal row's `ModificationDate`, not the `CreationDate`. How do I fix it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER CloneAfterUpdate
ON ProcessList
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE(Amount) OR UPDATE(Name))
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ProcessListHist (
           ID,
           Name,
           Amount,
           CreationDate,
           Edited,
           ModificationDate)
   SELECT 
      ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, 'Y', GETDATE() 
   FROM deleted
END
```

Trigger being called when executing this T-SQL:

```
UPDATE ProcessList 
SET Amount = 23000 
WHERE Name = 'Tammy'

SELECT * 
FROM ProcessList 

UNION ALL 

SELECT * 
FROM ProcessListHist 
ORDER BY ID ASC, CreationDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting out with sql but I think this might do it:

```
UPDATE ProcessList 
SET Amount = 23000 
WHERE Name = 'Tammy'

SELECT     ph.ID,
           ph.Name,
           ph.Amount,
           ph.CreationDate,
           ph.Edited,
           pl.ModificationDate,

FROM ProcessList pl
left join ProcessListHist ph
on pl.id=ph.id and pl.Name= ph.name and pl.CreationDate =ph.CreationDate
ORDER BY ID ASC, CreationDate ASC
```

This is untested and only to give you an idea. If this is incorrect, I apologize.